# How to write こたえ: 答え or 答?

Tags: kanji, readings, orthography, okurigana

In the microsoft IME keyboard, and my cellphone's as well, when I write こたえ it is suggested 答え. However, in the Genki I textbook, I've seen it written as

> 答{こたえ}

Are both of these valid? If so, which is more normal to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are valid, but 答え is more normal to use.
However, you cannot use 答る instead of 答える (verb).

Therefore,

> ○ 答えを見る。
>   ○ 答を見る。
>
> ○ その問いに答える。
>   × その問に答る。

References 
http://www.mext.go.jp/b_menu/hakusho/nc/k19730618001/k19730618001.html